# contains filter in Smarttable using defaultOperationMode Client

Tags: sapui5

my current setup:

- Smarttable
- personalisation Dialog (for Filter/Sorter)
- defaultOperationMode: Client side

## Problem

using client side filtering in general works.

But using contains is case sensitive. Why? (is it a framework bug)

**filtering using "contains" in smarttable works on "defaultOperationMode": "Auto"**

- not case sensitive *correct*

**filtering using "contains" in smarttable does NOT work on "defaultOperationMode": "Client"**

- case sensitive
- I have to write the "Cup" with capital letter to find the Cup 1, Cup 2,..

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client side, filtering is done in the stored JSON and JSON is case sensitive. `Object['field']` is different from `Object['Field']`. On the server side, you have your database dealing with some of your searches and especially in a HANA CDS this might take care of the case sensitivity of a CONTAINS statement.

If you want case insensitive searches on an old database or client side, you'll have to translate all strings and searches to either upper or lower case yourself I think.

Comment: thanks for the replay. since I am using the oDataV2 my understanding was that the data is still in the oData Model and not in a JSON. even the filter ist the same. but unfortunately not working in client mode. I will have to use your workaround, thank you.

Comment: I should clarify - the data is still in the oData model but that doesn't mean it's not stored as a json object